# Get media with Instagram Python API

Tags: python, json, api, instagram

I want to be able to list out the URLs of recent media items from an authorized account. This is the first time I've ever tried using the Python-Instagram API. I have all sensitive variables filled out in the following snippet.

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

access_token = ""
client_secret = ""
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)

user_id = ""

def get_media():
    request = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{USERID}/media/recent/?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}'
    response = urlopen(request).read().decode('utf8')
    obj = json.loads(response)

    for i in obj['data']['link']:
        print (i['link'])
```

This returns absolutely nothing.

`print (obj)` returns the json in plain text. (is this the proper way of doing things? Or are there calls in the API that do this like `api.get_recent_media()`?

Comment: Yes, there are calls in the api client library. I don't understand why you import and instantiate it if you then just make the request manually.

Comment: The API provides a `api.user_recent_media(user_id, count, max_id)` method. You can see the relationships between methods and endpoints [documented here](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: @CarlGroner I get a `KeyError: 'data'` when I use build in methods. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API provides a `user_recent_media` method. This is the example given in the [docs](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/README.md) on how to use it:

```
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media()
photos = []
for media in recent_media:
    photos.append('<img src="%s"/>' % media.images['thumbnail'].url)
```

The format of the response can be gleaned from the [endpoint documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent).